# reset theorem counter after every subsection and print just #subsection

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have declared `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem} \numberwithin{thm}{subsection}`.
This numbers every theorem in this format `[chapter].[section].[subsection].[numberofthm]`. Is it possible to have the counter just printing `[numberofthm]` instead?

Comment: You want to be mean to your readers. ;-) Your text will be full of “as we saw in Theorem 3 of subsection 2.9.42“. Just number them by section, uniquely throughout the document.

Comment: @egreg The OP's document features chapters. ;-)

Comment: Haha, its my teachers fault, he does the numbering that way. But it should be Ok, because each subsection is pretty different.

Comment: I can't check what this does without a MWE, but you could try `\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}` (after the two commands you did show us).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngcntr) package and its `\counterwithin*` macro -- the starred version changes the parent counter, but does not add/remove prefixes.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\counterwithin*{thm}{subsection} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\subsection{foobargnu}

\begin{thm}
A theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
A second theorem.
\end{thm}

\subsection{foobargnat}

\begin{thm}
A third theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]` and `\renewcommand{\thethm}{\arabic{thm}}` will do without any external package.